# AC compressor clutch snap ring holes covered up by something

Tags: ac, nissan, altima, compressor

I'm trying to get the snap ring out of the AC compressor clutch but the holes on the snap ring are covered up. It seems to come from below the holes and protruding out of the holes. I am leaving pictures here to explain things better.
I knocked off one of the bumps covering the hole with a snap ring plier. The picture doesn't show it clearly but the hole is still covered up after I broke off the top part.

That tip between the two holes can move from left to right by the way.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated right now here in Texas weather.

Nissan Altima 2.5 4L 2005

[image: ac compressor clutch snap ring]

[image: ac compressor clutch snap ring bump broken off]

Comment: Can’t you just poke the holes to clear them. Maybe use a small drill bit?

Comment: Looks to be like someone spot-welded through the holes. Maybe I'm misreading the pictures, though. However, _if_ that's the case, use a Dremel or the like to carefully grind down the snap ring. They shouldn't be reused anyways.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question?  If you are trying to remove the snap ring just use a flat bladed screw driver and Needle nose pliers and pry the two ends apart.  Be careful of the snap ring flying off.....

Comment: I'm trying to get the snap ring out of the AC compressor clutch but the holes on the snap ring are covered up. I can't use needle nose pliers. The holes for the needle nose pliers are covered up